springboot fragment for specific div section
I am building a programme in springboot I just started learning it.
I was able to include a whole title section into the base html but I have been looking for a way to include a specific div section in springboot.
I have googled if there is any way I can do that but I have not been able to find anything tangible
This is what I have done so far
base.html
<html lang="en">
    <head th:fragment="page(title)">
        <title th:replace="${title}">This is my default title </title>
        <!-- bootstrap css -->
            <link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/css/bootstrap.min.css}" />
            <!-- site css -->
            <link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/style.css}" />
            <!-- responsive css -->
            <link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/css/responsive.css}" />
            <!-- color css -->
            <link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/css/colors.css}" />
    </head>
    <body class="main_body" th:fragment="body(div_section1)">
        <div th:replace="${div_section1}"></div>
        <div class="logo_section">
                       <!-- <a href="index.html"><img class="logo_icon img-responsive" src="images/logo/logo_icon.png" alt="#" /></a>-->
               <a href="index.html"><img class="logo_icon img-responsive" th:src="@{/images/logo/logo_icon.jpeg}" alt="#"/></a>
                     </div>
    </body>

welcome_page.html
<html lang="en">
   <head th:replace="base :: page_title(~{::title}, )">
      <title>Welcome to My page</title>
   </head>
   <body th:replace="base :: body(div_section)">
    <div id="specific_links"><!-- this is the div section I want to include into a specific div section of the page
        <a href="@{/}"> <span>Home</span></a><br>
        <a href="@{/admin}"> <span>Admin</span></a><br>
        <a href="@{/account}"> <span>Account</span></a><br>
        <a href="@{/sales}"> <span>Sales</span></a><br>
       </div>
    <div id="specific_table"><!-- this is the div section I want to include into a specific div section of the page
        <tr><td>1</td><td>A1</td><td>B1</td></tr><br>
        <tr><td>2</td><td>A2</td><td>B2</td></tr><br>
        <tr><td>3</td><td>A3</td><td>B3</td></tr><br>
        <tr><td>4</td><td>A4</td><td>B4</td></tr><br>
       </div>
   </body>

I am able to insert the title but the div_section is not going thru. how can I insert a specific div section. I am hoping to insert multiple div section more like
th:replace="base :: body(specific_link, specific_table)". So within the base.html it would insert
